# How to search brightcove videos by tag in android

Tags: android, video-streaming, brightcove

In ios i can find **findVideosByTags:** function.

But in android i can't find such a method.

How can i search videos by its tag arry in android?

I cant find **BCItemCollection** in my suggesion list in eclipse.

i am trying to use the Catalog class.

```
com.brightcove.player.media.Catalog.Catalog(String token)
```

However,i cant find a method for serching a video by its tag.

I can find such a search class here `https://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/player/com/brightcove/api/search/VideoSearch.html#VideoSearch()`

but i cant get this package in eclipse.Which jar file need to add in my project and from where?

I am using only one library(brightcove jar v 4.1.17) in my project.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at that link is for the Flash player API, not the Android SDK. The `Catalog` class does not have a method to search by tag - you'd need to use Brightcove's [media API](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/media/guides/search_videos-guide.html) to do the search either with a direct HTTP request (or possibly [this Java wrapper](https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/Java-MAPI-Wrapper)) and use the response to construct `Video`s.